# unsupported media type error when posting to aspnetcore api from angular using $http.delete

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm getting a 415 http error result when posting to a aspnetcore api.
This doesn't happen if my endpoint is marked with [HttpPost] instead of [HttpDelete]

In the aspnetcore api controller:

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody]EntityViewModel vm)
{
```

In the angular controller:

```
 var obj = new Object();
 obj.atr1 = 1;
 obj.atr2 = 2 ;

 $http.post(route, obj)
    .then(function (response) {
```

EntityViewModel.cs

```
public class EntityViewModel
    {
        public int Atr1 { get; set; }
        public int Atr2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What sort of data type is yout API route expecting?

Comment: @SterlingArcher updated the question with the EntityViewModel class

Comment: My issue was because I had the `[FromBody]` attribute in my aspnet core method. Once I took it out, it was fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading your question first, I was confused a little bit ...

Why is a `$http.post` used to issue a DELETE request ? Why is `$http.delete` not used for this purpose ? Then I read more about AngularJS `$http.delete` and found that you cannot send a body to the server. Then I asked myself, why should you be able to send a body in a DELETE request. There is a nice question on this here: [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request) - The specs allow DELETE requests with body data.

To make a long story short...

ASP.NET Core can handle DELETE requests with JSON data sent in the body. So the controller part is valid.

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody]EntityViewModel vm)
{
```

In order to avoid the status code 415 (Unsupported Media Type) it is very important that the Header field `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`. I forgot this in my experiments with Postman as client and got the 415 status code as well.

For the AngularJS part I suggest to use

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.atr1 = 1;
obj.atr2 = 2 ;

$http(
  {
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: route,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: obj
  }
).then(function (response) {
```